# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I'm wondering if someone could help me out, I've tried searching beforehand but I'm unable to find an answer:

I have a file called info.dat which contains:

```
#
# *** Please be aware that the revision numbers on the control lines may not always
# *** be 1 more than the last file you received. There may have been additional
# *** increments in between.
#
$001,427,2018,04,26
#
# Save this file as info.dat
#
```

I'm trying to loop the file, get the version number and write that to its own file

```
with open('info.dat', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('$001,'):
            with open('version.txt', 'w') as w:
                version = line[5:8] # Should be 427
                w.write(version + '\n')
                w.close()
```

While this does write the correct info, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "~/Desktop/backup/test.py", line 4, in <module>
for line in file:
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 6281: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When trying to add the following

```
with open('info.dat', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('$001,'):
            with open('version.txt', 'w') as w:
                version = line[5:8]
                # w.write(version.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
                w.write(version.decode() + '\n')
                w.close()
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "~/Desktop/backup/test.py", line 9, in <module>
w.write(version.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: [blog post](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2015/05/21/python-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-uxfc-in-position-11-ordinal-not-in-range128/). The guy even tried to parse names of FC Bayern Munich, so he probably run into exactly the same umlauts (Süle, Götze) (the \0xe4 is the umlaut 'ä').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to open a text file, which will implicitly decode each line with your default encoding, then manually re-encode each line with UTF-8, then write it to a text file, which will implicitly decode that UTF-8 back using your default encoding again. That isn't going to work. But the good news is, the *right* thing to do is a lot simpler.

---

If you know the input file is in UTF-8 (which it probably isn't—see below), just open the files as UTF-8 instead of as your default encoding:

```
with open('info.dat', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('$001,'):
            with open('version.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as w:
                version = line[5:8] # Should be 427
                w.write(version + '\n')
                w.close()
```

In fact, I'm pretty sure your files are *not* in UTF-8, but Latin-1 (in Latin-1, `\xa3` is `ä`; in UTF-8, it's the start of a 3-byte sequence that probably encodes a CJK character). If so, you can do the same thing with the right encoding instead of the wrong one, and now it will work.

---

But if you have no idea what the encoding is, don't try to guess; just stick with binary mode. This means passing `rb` and `wb` modes instead of `r` and `w`, and using `bytes` literals:

```
with open('info.dat', 'rb') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith(b'$001,'):
            with open('version.txt', 'wb') as w:
                version = line[5:8] # Should be 427
                w.write(version + b'\n')
                w.close()
```

---

Either way, no need to call `encode` or `decode` anywhere; just let the file objects take care of it for you, and deal with only a single type (whether `str` or `bytes`) everywhere.

Comment: Thank you, very much for the explanation that helped quite a lot!

Answer (score 1):

encode() return bytes, but '\n' is string, you need to transform string in bytes to be bytes + bytes so try this

```
w.write(version.encode('utf-8') + b'\n')
```

Comment: That solves one of the exceptions he ran into with one of his two incorrect attempted solutions, it it doesn't actually solve the problem. Reading text with the wrong codec and then transcoding it multiple times to build mojibake on mojibake can't be fixed by adding yet another transcode.